# Undisclosed relative

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, long-stay-visas

I have been granted a visit visa and visited the UK 4 times. When I made my last visit my daughter was living in the UK, but I didn't mention her. Now I want to apply for a long-term visit visa. Would my earlier omission result in a refusal?

Comment: We cannot tell you for sure, but indeed the situation created is quite dangerous (you might get not only refusal but also ban if they decide you tried to deceit them). Omitting your daughter doesn't look like an innocent overlooking either. You should definitely talk to a licensed attorney with relevant experience before proceeding.

Comment: Was it a case of simply didn't mention, or did you answer "No" to "Do you have any relatives in the UK?" either on an application or during an interview?

Comment: answered "NO" in that field